# Rails: CanCanCan to limit number of resource creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancancan

I'm using CanCanCan gem for my rails app. I want to limit number of `page` creation based on user subscription plan. e.g. user having `basic` plan can only  create maximum of 10 pages. How can I achieve it? I've tried to introduce a limitation by using following rule:

`can :create, :pages if user.subscription_plan == "basic" && Page.count <= 10`

But as soon as my page number exceeds 10 it block access to every controller on `pages` controller. I'm using following code on `pages` controller.

```
before_action :authorize_user
.
.
.

def authorize_user
  authorize! :create, :pages
rescue => e
  redirect_to admin_path, :alert => "You've reached your page creation limit."
end
```

How best to achieve my required affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your before action is triggered for every action in the controller. Limit it to 'create' action:

```
before_action :authorize_user, only: :create
```